# Como ocultar campos em consultas usando eloquent laravel atraves do metodo Join

Tags: php, laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

De uma pergunta, Me foi passado uma forma de fazer consultas com objetos filhos usando o Join do eloquent, A consulta está abaixo:

```
$dados = Roda::join('veiculos', function($query) {
    $query->on('veiculos.id', '=', 'rodas.veiculo_id');
    $query->where('veiculo.cor', '=', 'vermelho');
})
->get();
```

Porem, Agora surge a necessidade de ocultar campos que vem no objeto, e eu não sei como fazer isto usando o modelo do Join que é visto acima, o codigo resolve um outro problema, que não conseguir resolver de outra forma. Agora surge preciso ocultar campos, Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o método [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects) passando por parâmetro um `array` com o nome dos campos que deseja retornar.

```
$dados = Roda::join('veiculos', function($query) {
    $query->on('veiculos.id', '=', 'rodas.veiculo_id');
    $query->where('veiculo.cor', '=', 'vermelho');
})
->select(['rodas.cor', 'rodas.modelo'])
->get();
```

[Documentação do `select()`.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects)

Comment: Pra eu fechar a pergunta, Poderia disponibilizar a documentação onde vc se baseia para responder?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs — é possível notar que quando eu falo em métodos eu coloco links pra documentação deles.

Comment: Em que pagina? pq eu não consegui achar nada do que vc me ensinou nos dois posts. Poderia ser um pouco mais especifico?

Comment: É só você usar a caixa de busca. O que você precisa de especificação? Nos dois posts tem links **pras páginas exatas** que eu consultei.